# Google maps V2 can not open inside HomeFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer app consist of 5 fragment on the drawer. I want to put google maps v2 activity inside the HomeFragment (the first and default fragment of navigation drawer), but first i tried to put everything it should be on MainActivity on java and activity_main on xml and everything was running well. But i'd like to put it on HomeFragment only, not at whole fragment, so i move the googleMaps code lines from MainActivity to HomeFragment activity and it gone error.

Here is my java code:

```
    package com.mage.unjukrasaid.navigationdrawer.fragment;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    import com.mage.unjukrasaid.R;

    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
     * {@link HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
     * to handle interaction events.
     * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    //        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
    //            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    //        } else {
    //            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
    //                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    //        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

And here is my xml code fragment_home:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mage.unjukrasaid.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/mapss" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

On the logcat, here is what it said:

> 02-02 17:41:12.983 3491-3491/com.mage.unjukrasaid E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.mage.unjukrasaid, PID: 3491
>                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                           at
>   com.mage.unjukrasaid.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment.initilizeMap(HomeFragment.java:92)
>                                                                           at
>   com.mage.unjukrasaid.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment.onResume(HomeFragment.java:83)
>                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2238)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1346)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:967)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

it said on HomeFragment line 92 and 83, but i don't know what makes it error

May be you guys have a brilliant solution, i will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager() as you're inside a Fragment. SO your code shoud be:

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It said ''Cannot resolve method 'getChildFragmentManager()'", any ideas what should i import ?

Comment: @VickySultan take a look at the edit. Sorry, it shoudn't be getActivity() but simply this as you're already in the fragment.

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Has been a while since I worked with Google's MAP API. But as far as I can remember I used to do things slightly diferente. First, assuming that your using Android Studio IDE.

Right click on your main package -> New -> Google > Google Maps Activity. 
This will create Activity that inherits from "FragmentActivity" and implements OnMapReadyCallBack.

Now, make your Fragment.Class a SupportMapFragment's subclass.

### Know that you have an superficial overview, go to the [API's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map) to deeper details.